# Why does Visual Studio 2015 code completion suddenly stop working?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I'm using Windows 8, and VS2015 with Resharper. Whilst working, I find that halfway through editing a file, code completion will suddenly stop working, and I'll have to restart to regain the functionality. I've checked in the Options for the C# language, and both code complete checkboxes are ticked.

Are there known issues with Resharper and 2015, or is there some checkbox that I haven't ticked somewhere?

Using Resharper 9.2

Comment: Which version of ReSharper?

Comment: Try this Tools /Import and export settings / Reset all settings

Comment: @LexLi Resharper 9.2

Comment: @user3791372 current version is 10.x so not sure if this is a known issue for 9.x.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper and Visual Studio can interact in bad ways, including using a lot of memory. Your precise problem will need some diagnostics.

However, first thing to check. Is your system running low on RAM? If so, turn *off* some of the options - for example Solution Wide Analysis. See [ReSahrper slowness](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546919-Visual-Studio-with-ReSharper-is-slow/) for other things to check and try.

If these do not help [JetBrains](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546149-Visual-Studio-with-ReSharper-is-freezing-and-or-crashing) provide some other things to look for for crashes or freezes most of which are version specific. Note - at the bottom of this page it states:

> After acquiring as much information as possible, please contact JetBrains ReSharper Support Team using the 'Submit a request' form above and letting us know about the issue with detailed description. Our team will guide you and provide further steps to troubleshoot the issues